# Reverse bubble sort (biggest to the left) doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, reverse, bubble-sort

I want to sort 12 integers using a "reverse bubble sort" (We call it "the drowning axe sort", whatever). My function looks good to me but something goes wrong.

Error: having typed my 12 random numbers I don't get the result printed, instead my compiler stops and does not proceed any further.

Can anyone help?

Code:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<math.h>

void array_clean(int a[11]) //just an array cleaner
{
  for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
  {
     a[i] = a[i]&&0; // smth && 0 = 0 anyway
  }
}

void axe_sort(int a[11]) //drowning-axe sort function
{
    int place = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<12; j++)
        {
            if(a[j]<a[j+1])
                place=a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = place;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[11]; //declaring an integer array;
    array_clean(& array[11]); // giving user-filed array to a cleaner function
    printf("Enter 12 random integers you'd like to sort: ");
    for(int m=0; m<12; m++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[m]); //letting user to fill an array
    }
    axe_sort(&array[11]); //sorting an array via our axe_sort function
    for(int m=0; m<12; m++)
    {
        printf("%d", array[m]); //printing the sorted array
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your *compiler stops and goes no further*, it gives you compiler errors that tell you why it stopped. Why aren't those messages in your post?

Comment: What makes you think you need `a[i] = a[i]&&0`? Why can't you just do `a[i] = 0`?

Comment: @KenWhite most likely a terminology error.  If the compiler stopped, then there wouldn't be a program to execute, making entry of the numbers impossible.  I suspect he meant the program stopped, which is a far more likely outcome all things considered.

Comment: @KenWhite i use xcode. it shows this: 122334455667788990243546(lldb) and stops worling

Answer (score 1):

Your array `int array[11];` isn't doing what you think it is.  That declares an array of 11 ints, indexed from 0 to 10 inclusive.  There is no `array[11]` therefore trying to access this will lead to undefined behavior.

You've got the correct form of your `for` loop, it'll correctly iterate over 12 members of the array, numbered 0 to 11 inclusive.  However you need to declare the array as `int array[12];` to get it big enough to work.

Also, you're passing the array to the two functions using `&array[11]`.  You just need to say `array` and it'll pass in the array correctly.  What you're doing will cause the two functions to write over random memory, which definitely won't help.

Try fixing these and see what changes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You should include `stdio.h` header file in order to use `printf()` and `scanf()`

You are dealing with 12 integers. Then Why did you declare an array of 11 integers???

```
int array[11]; //declaring an integer array;  <-------- change the size to 12 from 11
```

The purpose of the `array_clean();` is to initialize each number with 0. You can simply put 0 instead of `a[i]&&0;`

Here you are passing the address of 12th element.

```
array_clean(&array[11]); //<---------------------
```

You should pass the address of the `base element(1st)`.
You can do this by two ways.

```
 array_clean(&array[0]); 
 Or,
 array_clean(array);
```

**When an array is used as a value, its name represents the address of the first element.**

And finally, please check your `bubble` sort logic.

```
    for(int j=0; j<12; j++)
            {
                if(a[j]<a[j+1])
                    {place=a[j]; //<-----curly braces missing in the body of if 
                    a[j] = a[j+1];  //<----error
                    a[j+1] = place;
                    }

            }
```

For j=11, your code will try to access 12th index and that will give you a `segmentation fault`. Enclose the body of `if` with `curly braces`.

Here is the modified code

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h> // <---------- include this header file 

void array_clean(int a[12]) //just an array cleaner
  {
       for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
       a[i] = 0; // smth && 0 = 0 anyway
    }

  }

void axe_sort(int a[12]) //drowning-axe sort function
{
  int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<11-i; j++)  //<-------- see the logic carefully
        {
            if(a[j] < a[j+1])   //<-----put curly braces
                {int place=a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = place;}
        }
    }

}

    int main(void)
     {
        int array[12]; //declaring an integer array;
        array_clean(&array[0]); // <---------------- pass the base address
        printf("Enter 12 random integers you'd like to sort: ");
        for(int m=0; m<12; m++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &array[m]); //letting user to fill an array
        }
         axe_sort(&array[0]); // <---------------- pass the base address
        for(int m=0; m<12; m++)
        {
            printf("%d ", array[m]); //printing the sorted array
        }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you forgot to include the stdio.h library in your code

Comment: I recommend adding to this answer why you think this and how will it help the Asker. This will make a more complete answer.